# Enable TLS and Disable SSL via PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl

I'm looking to automate disabling SSL protocols 2 & 3 as well as disable TLS 1.0 while enabling and enforcing TLS 1.1 & 1.2. I created a PowerShell script based on some blog I read, however, I don't like the way the my script looks. I like building scripts the right way when it comes to scale and best practices. I don't even know how to start but I think theres a better way to write this.

I've ran the script just fine. Works perfectly.

```bsh
function disable-ssl-2.0 {
    New-Item ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server’ -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server’ -Name Enabled -Value 0 –PropertyType DWORD
    Write-Host "Disabling SSLv2"
}
function disable-ssl-3.0 {
    New-Item ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server’ -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server’ -Name Enabled -Value 0 –PropertyType DWORD
    Write-Host "Disabling SSLv3"
}
function disable-tls-1.0 {
    New-Item “HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\PROTOCOLS” –Name “TLS 1.0”
    New-Item “HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\PROTOCOLS\TLS 1.0” –Name SERVER
    New-ItemProperty “HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\PROTOCOLS\TLS 1.0\SERVER” –Name Enabled –Value 0 –Type DWORD
    Write-Host "Disabling TLSv1.0"
}
function enable-tls-1.1 {
    New-Item ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server’ -Force
    New-Item ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client’ -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server’ -Name ‘Enabled’ -Value ‘0xffffffff’ –PropertyType DWORD
    New-ItemProperty -Path ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server’ -Name ‘DisabledByDefault’ -Value 0 –PropertyType DWORD
    New-ItemProperty -Path ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client’ -Name ‘Enabled’ -Value 1 –PropertyType DWORD
    New-ItemProperty -Path ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client’ -Name ‘DisabledByDefault’ -Value 0 –PropertyType DWORD
    Write-Host "Enabling TLSv1.1"
}
function enable-tls-1.2 {
    New-Item ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server’ -Force
    New-Item ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client’ -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server’ -Name ‘Enabled’ -Value ‘0xffffffff’ –PropertyType DWORD
    New-ItemProperty -Path ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server’ -Name ‘DisabledByDefault’ -Value 0 –PropertyType DWORD
    New-ItemProperty -Path ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client’ -Name ‘Enabled’ -Value 1 –PropertyType DWORD
    New-ItemProperty -Path ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client’ -Name ‘DisabledByDefault’ -Value 0 –PropertyType DWORD
    Write-Host "Enabling TLSv1.2"
}

disable-ssl-2.0
disable-ssl-3.0
disable-tls-1.0
enable-tls-1.1
enable-tls-1.2
```

Maybe I should compress the registry commands by assigning variables maybe? Just not sure how to make this script more professional.

Comment: Maybe this is better placed here : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: May I suggest to replace all the curlu 'smart-quotes' into straight ones

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this doesnt answer the formatting question but I added to the script for those who are interested in a more refined registry setup removing older encryptions.

```
function disable-ssl-2.0
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server' -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value '0' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value '1' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    Write-Host 'Disabling SSLv2'
}
function disable-ssl-3.0
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server' -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    Write-Host 'Disabling SSLv3'
}
function disable-tls-1.0
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -Force
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client' -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value '1' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value '0' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value '1' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    Write-Host 'Disabling TLSv1.0'
}
function enable-tls-1.1
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -Force
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '1' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value '0' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value '1' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value '0' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    Write-Host 'Enabling TLSv1.1'
}
function enable-tls-1.2
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -Force
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '1' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value '0' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value '1' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value '0' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
    Write-Host 'Enabling TLSv1.2'
}
function enforce-tls-versions
{
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\PPP\EAP\13' -Name 'TlsVersion'  -value 'F00' –PropertyType 'DWORD'
}

disable-ssl-2.0
disable-ssl-3.0
disable-tls-1.0
enable-tls-1.1
enable-tls-1.2
enforce-tls-versions
```

Comment: What does the enforce-tls-versions section do?

Comment: According to Microsoft support its for legacy OS’s like Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012 R2, and Windows RT for the Microsoft Extensible Authentication Protocol (EAP) implementation that enables the use of Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.1 or 1.2 through the modification of the system registry. To enable TLS after you install this security update, you must add a DWORD value.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977292/microsoft-security-advisory-update-for-microsoft-eap-implementation-th