# Enable and Disable TLS and SSL in IE on windows 10 local machine(not windows server) using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl, internet-explorer, tls1.2

I've been reading some articles and Microsoft docs and looking at some StackOverflow questions to change/toggle tls and ssl settings in internet explorer(IE) in Advanced Tab but these scripts got me nowhere. Till now I've tried [Enable TLS and Disable SSL via PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55914397/enable-tls-and-disable-ssl-via-powershell-script)

https://medium.com/think-stack/disabling-tls-1-0-on-your-workstations-eb8377a2bd09

and some other scripts which have pointed me to the same directory.

A registry is being made at that path but tls and ssl settings do not change.

Please, help me where am I making mistake. Thanks in advance.

[image: Picture of tls and ssl settings of IE browser]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reg key for IE TLS and SSL setting is under this path:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

[image]

The reg key is **SecureProtocols**. Each protocol you circle in the picture modifies the same registry key, the DWORD value will be a hexadecimal sum of the decimal value of each check box. You can check/uncheck the options in IE setting to observe how the **SecureProtocols** value is changing.

For example, if you want to check all the options, the value should be **0x00002aa0 (10912)**. The PowerShell script should be like this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -name 'SecureProtocols' -value '0x00002aa0' -Type DWord
Write-Host 'Enable All'
```

The other situations are similar, you just need to change the value of the reg key.

Comment: thank you so much. I've been working on this for many days. Please can you share a link or something like that for other value of tls and ssl registry

Comment: Also from this https://admx.help/?Category=InternetExplorer&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::Advanced_SetWinInetProtocols  I find total 31 combinations is there any other way to enable or disable one tls or ssl property one at a time?

Comment: I don't have a link for other values. Yes, there're many combinations and I just test some combinations and get the values. As all the protocols use the same registry key, I think there's no other way to enable or disable one property at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI the above answer fixed my issue (THANKS!), but in my case I wanted 10240 as the value so that SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are turned off. You can toggle the individual values more easily by running "inetcpl.cpl" to pull up Internet Options, and go to the Advanced tab and look there for the security protocols.